# CORS error while trying to upload an image

Tags: image, wcf, cors, access-control

I am working on a Backbone.js based web application which communicates with a WCF service and uploads a "complaint" to an SQL database. The complaint model has various attributes like title, description etc. It also has an ImageByte attribute so users can upload images relevant to that complaint. I am sending the image to the WCF service as Base64 string.

I have gone through all relevant questions regarding solving these cross-origin errors and have tried them. What's weird and different with my problem is that when I send a complaint model without the image, everything works just fine and smooth. But when I add the ImageByte to the model, I get the same old error.

```
Origin http://localhost:55708 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I don't understand what's happening here. If it's a cross domain communication problem, it should be giving me the error even without the image string. Has this something to do with the length of the content being sent? I'm sending the whole model as JSON.

Any sort of explanation/help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found out that it's because of the length of the JSON data being passed. Still don't understand why this was happening but the error got solved when I added the following to the web.config file

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="100000000" maxBytesPerRead="100000000" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.